# the method build() is undefined for Notification.builder

Tags: java, android, libraries

I'm going crazy building a notification.
i read in the web that i need to update my libraries.
I went to right-click on the project ; proprieties and i unchecked and , after download the last package, re-cheched my libraries android.support.v7.
when I restart eclipse i have the same error.
i think that i don't know how update libs. help me please
EDIT: I CHANGED notification.builder to notificationcompat.builder()
i can compile the project but now i have this errorlog

```
package com.example.simplenotification;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;

 private int mNotificationCount;

 private final CharSequence tickerText ="this is tickerText";
 private final CharSequence contentTitle="this contentTitle";
 private final CharSequence contentText="this coontentText";

 private Intent mNotificationIntent;
 private PendingIntent mContentIntent;

 RemoteViews mContentView = new RemoteViews("com.example.simplenotification.StatusBarWithCustomView", R.layout.custom_view);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNotificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AppGet.class);
    mContentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, mNotificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v){
            mContentView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1, contentText + "(" + ++mNotificationCount +")");


            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setTicker(tickerText)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_more)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(mContentIntent)
            .setContent(mContentView);

            NotificationManagerCompat mNotificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(MainActivity.this);
            mNotificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID,notificationBuilder.build());
        }


        }



    });



 }
```

}

ERROR LOG SHOW THIS :

```
09-18 11:19:22.344: E/AndroidRuntime(978): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-18 11:19:22.344: E/AndroidRuntime(978): android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad       notification posted from package com.example.simplenotification: Couldn't expand   RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification(package=com.example.simplenotification id=0 tag=null  notification=Notification(contentView=com.example.simplenotification.StatusBarWithCustomView/0x7f030019 vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0,flags=0x10) priority=0)
09-18 11:19:22.344: E/AndroidRuntime(978):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1259)
09-18 11:19:22.344: E/AndroidRuntime(978):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-18 11:19:22.344: E/AndroidRuntime(978):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-18 11:19:22.344: E/AndroidRuntime(978):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
09-18 11:19:22.344: E/AndroidRuntime(978):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-18 11:19:22.344: E/AndroidRuntime(978):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-18 11:19:22.344: E/AndroidRuntime(978):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-18 11:19:22.344: E/AndroidRuntime(978):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-18 11:19:22.344: E/AndroidRuntime(978):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: pls put logcat errors

Comment: "your project contain error(s) please fix them before running your application"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code as below:

```
public void onClick(View v){

            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setTicker(tickerText)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_more)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(mContentIntent)

            NotificationManagerCompat mNotificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
            mNotificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID,notificationBuilder.build());
        }
```

Comment: it don't found with context "this" I changed "this" with "MainActivity.this" and i can compile it but I have the error that I post in the edit answer.

Comment: I have updated the code. Here I have removed the RemoteViews in which I guess you are adding the layout of notification. See if above code can remove the error you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need support library version 4 if you want to use the notification builder from the support library. Try to import

```
android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
```

and use:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
```

I assumed you wanted to use the support version since you were talking about the support library. Otherwise if you want to use the normal notificationbuilder, i don't see where the error is. Added this as an answer since i don't have enough rep to comment.